# Wso2 API orchestration requirement for API Management

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager, orchestration, ibm-api-management

We successfully launch Wso2 API management solution. One of the main functionality of our project is to orchestrate several simple API and make one Meta API. Then we want to publish this Meta API into Wso2 API Management Publisher and make it available to use.
Is any solution to this requirement?

Comment: What do you mean by several simple APIs? Can you add more details?

Comment: For a simple example we want to chain couple of APIs, answer of one API will be send to next API (without programming). We want a solution to easily manage this chain or orchestration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this. If I understand you correct, you only want to publish the meta api as a managed api. Other simple apis won't be published. If so, things are pretty easy.

[WSO2 API Manager](http://wso2.com/products/api-manager/) uses Apache Synapse as the mediation engine (which is used by WSO2 ESB too). This allows to do the chaining. Please go through the following articles.

1. http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/03/batch-api-api-chaining-scenario/
2. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/Service+Chaining+Example
3. http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/09/get-cup-coffee-wso2-way/